# Getting one item out of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a homepage with different products and I want to display one choosen product in anouther view. (the detail view). To show the products I use ng-repeat, which iterate over an product-Array.

Now I get a single product out of the ng-repeat when cklicking an button. Then the view changes into the detail view with the choosen product. The switch of the views should go over the id, because this one is needed to make an request to my API.

At this state I tried it with $routeParams, but it'doesn't workted. Then I searched here on stackoverflow. I read that it could be scope-Problem, because I try to pass the id into an controller. (and I need that Id in another controller).
When I click the Button on the homepage, nothing happents.

I hope, that somebody has an idea, how to solve this problem.

Here is a stample json file of the API:

```
 {
   "_id": "582ae2beda0fd7f858c109e7",
   "title": "Lorem ipsum",
    "smalldescription": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,",
   "longdescription": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum ",
   "price": "2500",
   "img": "Imagetxt"
 }
```

Here is my Code:

app.js

```
angular.module('Productportfolio', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: '/components/home/home.html',
            controller: 'ProductCtrl'
        })

        .when('/detail/:productId', {
            templateUrl: '/components/detail/detail.html',
            controller: 'DetailCtrl'

        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
}]);
```

home.html

```
<div ng-controller="ProductCtrl as ProductCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="product in ProductCtrl.products ">
        <h3>{{product.title}}</h3>
            <button ng-click="loadDetail(product)">Detailansicht</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

ProductCtrl.js

```
 angular.module('Productportfolio')

.controller('ProductCtrl', ['APIService','$location', function (APIService,$location) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.products = null;

    init();

    function init() {
        APIService.getProducts()
            .then(function (response) {
               vm.products = response.data;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("error at GET");
            });
    }

    vm.loadDetail = function(product){
        $location.path('/detail'+product.id);
    }
}]);
```

APISvc.js

```
angular.module('Productportfolio')

.service('APIService', ['$http', function ($http) {

    var svc = this;
    svc.root = 'http://localhost:3000/api';

    svc.API = {
        'getProducts': getProducts,
        'getProduct' : getProduct
    };
    return svc.API;

    function getProducts() {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: svc.root + '/products'
        })
    }

    function getProduct(id){
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url : svc.root +'/product/'+id
        })
    }
}]);
```

DetailCtrl.js

```
 angular.module('Productportfolio')

.controller('DetailCtrl', ['APIService', '$routeParams', function (APIService, $routeParams) {


    var vm = this;
    vm.product = null;
    vm.productId = $routeParams.productId;

    init();

    function init() {
        APIService.getProduct(vm.productId)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                vm.product = response.data;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("error at GET");
            });
    }
}]);
```

Comment: check path in vm.loadDetail() function. I think it is  $location.path('/detail/'+product.id);

Comment: Year, your're right. I changed it and nothing happens when clicking on the Button. And I don't know if the approach is right of commit the product with ng-click

Comment: Can you try removing the ng-controller from div ?

Comment: I tried it and now nothing was shown; I have a white page

Comment: remove ng-controller from div and add as syntax to the route provider `controller: 'ProductCtrl as ProductCtrl'`

Answer (score 1):

Remove ng-controller from div and update like below.

```
<div >
    <div ng-repeat="product in vm.products ">
        <h3>{{product.title}}</h3>
        <button ng-click="vm.loadDetail(product)">Detailansicht</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also in route configuration add controllerAs: 'vm'

```
.when('/home', {
    templateUrl: '/components/home/home.html',
    controller: 'ProductCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
})
```

Update the function like

```
vm.loadDetail = function(product){
    $location.path('/detail'+product['_id']);
}
```

Comment: Does it mean, that I don't need the ng-controller because its defined in the module, right?

Comment: Ok, but the view isn't connected to the view, because I got a white site an with the ng-controller I get the right view

Comment: I was wrong, upps, I didn't used the ProductCtrl in my ng-repeat. Now I using `ng-repeat = product in ProductCtrl.products` and it workes. And the ng-controller is deleted.

Comment: You have included <div ng-view></div> in your main html right?

Comment: @AmeLives I have updated the answer. Please add controller as syntax in  route config. and no need to use ProductCtrl.products in html

Comment: I made the change and have a white page (again), so I use the Proudct.Ctrl again

Comment: Its because you are mixing two answers. Pls go ahead with any of this answers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128455/discussion-between-paulson-peter-and-ame-lives).

Comment: I added `ng-click="HomeCtrl.loadDetail(product)"` the button, like you said an now I got an visual feedback (side reload)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your module file with this this

```
angular.module('Productportfolio', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: '/components/home/home.html',
            controller: 'ProductCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'ProductCtrl'  //modified as your using controller as syntax
        })

        .when('/detail/:productId', {
            templateUrl: '/components/detail/detail.html',
            controller: 'DetailCtrl',
            controllerAs : 'DetailCtrl'     //modify this also              

            //add these lines
            param:{
            productId:null
            }
        }

        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
}]);
```

Replace your ProductCtrl.js with this

```
angular.module('Productportfolio')

.controller('ProductCtrl', ['APIService','$location', function (APIService,$location) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.products = null;

    init();

    function init() {
        APIService.getProducts()
            .then(function (response) {
               vm.products = response.data;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("error at GET");
            });
    }

    vm.loadDetail = function(product){
        $location.path('/detail/'+product._id); // you missed a slash and the property was wrong
    }
}]);
```

this is the correct one
            $location.path('/detail/'+product._id);

Comment: what does "param: pruductId: null"  mean?

Comment: @AmeLives updated the post. Please try with the new one. If you didnt get this right let me know!

Comment: It doesn't work. I think it's because of "param: pruductId: null". My IDE shows me an error, because it expected an , pruductId ans null -->                      `param:
                productId,null`

Comment: I include it, but I get no reaction of the page :/ and no errors on my console

Comment: @AmeLives your sample json please?

Comment: I add it to the post obove

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
As @Paulson Peter said:

Remove ng-controller from div and update like below.

```
<div >
  <div ng-repeat="product in vm.products ">
     <h3>{{product.title}}</h3>
     <button ng-click="vm.loadDetail(product)">Detailansicht</button>
 </div>
```

Also in route configuration add controllerAs: 'vm'

```
.when('/home', {
   templateUrl: '/components/home/home.html',
   controller: 'ProductCtrl',
   controllerAs: 'vm'
 })
```

Like @ Aravind said:

```
  vm.loadDetail = function(product){
     $location.path('/detail/'+product._id); //here is the change
   }
```

Now I can get the product an the view changes

Comment: $location.path('/detail/'+product._id); //here is the change this is the fix by me!!

Comment: I can't mark it as an answer, because I's my own and I have to wait 2 days til now

Comment: I added my Controller As as well.. I think you didnt try my solution completely